# C++, динамическая компоновка

Tags: c++, cmake

Есть динамическая библиотека(своя). Она использует другие библиотеки.
Собираю под Linux, используя CMake.
Приложение использует хидеры из этой библиотеки, чтобы наследоваться и прочее.

Проблема: Мне приходится в обязательном порядке в приложении указывать те же библиотеки, что использует моя библиотека. А так же приходится явно указывать все папки с хидерами(но это нормально уже). Есть вариант НЕ указывать библиотеки, которые использует моя библиотека(в ней они и так указываются при сборке)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А почему бы не использовать плюшки самого `cmake`, чтобы избежать лишней возни?

Если у вас есть библиотека, вроде:

```
add_library(mylib ${mylib_SRC})
```

то логично использовать эту же цель и для других сборок:

```
add_executable(myexe main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myexe PRIVATE mylib)
```

Заголовочники же можно указать как `PUBLIC` или `INTERFACE`, чтобы они автоматом подключались для цели, к которой будет слинкована библиотека

```
target_include_directories(mylib PUBLIC mylib_include_dir)
```

Comment: Это в пространстве одного CMakeLists.txt ?
Два проекта, два конфига сборки. Во втором подключаю либу и хидеры. Начинаются проблемы с библиотеками, подключенными в моей библиотеке.

Comment: @ПавелДрушляков а вы вообще в курсе такой фичи `cmake` как `add_subdirectory`?

Comment: Два **отдельных** проекта. Буквально, я сейчас соберу библиотеку, её хидеры и на другом ПК создам новый проект, включу туда эту библиотеку и получу проблемы, потому что не указал в нём библиотеки, используемые в моей. Задача стоит именно такая. Собрать библиотеку и тут же приложение на ней я могу.

Comment: и... ну два "отдельных" и что? Что это меняет?

Comment: Вы мне предлагаете в каждом новом проекте, использующем библиотеку, указывать директорию исходников этой библиотеки и собирать её?

Comment: 1) если вы до сих пор не поняли, что вы должны компилятору указывать директории с исходниками, которые используете - то я не понимаю как у вас вообще получается что-то писать.

Comment: 2) Перечитайте мой ответ - вот что я предлагаю

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91471/discussion-between---and-andrej-levkovitch).

Comment: 3) чтобы в каждом новом проекте, который будет зависеть от вашей библиотеки, не приходилось ее пересобирать, то вам стоит вспомнить, что find_package еще никто не отменял